# vba list array from row 18 onwards?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which lists unique values from an array:

```
Sub LIST()
  Dim arr As New Collection, a
  Dim aFirstArray() As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  aFirstArray() = Array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Tomato", "Apple", _
  "Lemon", "Lime", "Lime", "Apple")

  On Error Resume Next
  For Each a In aFirstArray
     arr.Add a, a
  Next


  For i = 18 To arr.Count
     Cells(i, 3) = arr(i)
  Next

End Sub
```

I want to list these values from row 18 onwards, but when I set I = 18 this doesn't work an nothing is listed. Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I believe you want `For i = 18 to 18 + arr.Count`.  Currently, `arr.count` will be 9 (or 7), and you can't do `for i = 18 to [any number less than 18]`

Comment: There are only 7 itmes in the collection and you are trying to reference number 18

Comment: `For i = 1 To arr.Count: Cells(i + 17, 3) = arr(i): Next`

Comment: OK - It must be late in the evening where you people are (you know who I am talking about @BruceWayne and Scott Craner!) - there should only be **SIX** items in `arr` - "Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Tomato", "Lemon" and "Lime".  (Or am I missing something!!)

Comment: @YowE3K I counted lime twice, it is past my nap time.

Comment: And it must be very late for @ScottCraner - he can't even spell "items" ;-)

Comment: @ScottCraner - It's past my nap time too (and it's only 8:27am!)

Comment: Go pet your kangaroo and let me sleep. @YowE3K

Comment: @YowE3K but it is already Friday for you.  I still have to finish today and work tomorrow.

Comment: @ScottCraner - my kangaroo is down in the parking stable where I left him when I rode him to work today - I'm too tired to go downstairs at the moment, but I will tell him you said hi when I go home this afternoon

Comment: @YowE3K - Haha, yeah yeah.....truth time: so I didn't even really pay total attention to the whole macro ( :X ) but the issue should be easily solved regardless with my brilliant suggestion of just doing `For i = 18 to 18 + arr.count` ....right?

Comment: @BruceWayne - well.... It would have to be `18 To 18 + arr.count - 1`, and it should be pointed out that it would need to be `Cells(i, 3) = arr(i - 17)` .... but you did get the `18` part right!!  ;-)  (And, on a serious note, the "and you can't do for i = 18 to [any number less than 18]" part was definitely something that needed to be said.)

Comment: @YowE3K bah! I was close and forgot the zero index, good call! ...And it looks like user3598756 ignored us anyways and has a really nice alternative anyways :D

Comment: @BruceWayne - Yeah - I guess I should stop adding "too chatty" comments to the question and instead +1 that answer and then get back to work.  No, I shouldn't - it doesn't work!

Comment: I wasn't ignoring you all. I was just unaware of you and now that I come back to this post I'm reading about kangaroo and indexes. So YowE3K are you Australian?

Comment: @user3598756 - what makes you think that ?!?!? :D  Note: your answer seems to only put 6 x "Banana" in the output - ahh - it needs to be an `Application.Transpose(.Keys)`

Comment: @YowE3K, yes, I left a `Transpose` somewhere along the road. Fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @user3598756 - **NOW** you can have a +1  (Probably my kangaroo saw the `Transpose` beside the road and stomped on it.)

Answer (score 2):

You could switch to Dictionary object and exploit its Keys property:

```
Sub LIST()
    Dim aFirstArray() As Variant, a As Variant

    aFirstArray() = Array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Tomato", "Apple", "Lemon", "Lime", "Lime", "Apple")

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each a In aFirstArray
            .Item(a) = a
        Next
        Cells(18, 3).Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @user7415328, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

Or remove the duplicates after:

```
arr = Array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Tomato", "Apple", "Lemon", "Lime", "Lime")
Set r = [C18].Resize(UBound(arr) + 1)
r = Application.Transpose(arr)
r.RemoveDuplicates 1
```